# Derived SASS classes

Tags: css, sass

I have the following in my SASS file which is used to display flags. I want to create three classes from this so that I can have small, medium and large size flags.

```
.flag-icon-background {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.flag-icon {
  @extend .flag-icon-background;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: (4 / 3) * 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  &:before {
    content: '\00a0';
  }
  &.flag-icon-squared {
    width: 1em;
  }
}

@mixin flag-icon($country) {
  .flag-icon-#{$country} {
    background-image: url(#{$flag-icon-css-path}#{$flag-icon-rect-path}/#{$country}.svg);
    &.flag-icon-squared {
      background-image: url(#{$flag-icon-css-path}#{$flag-icon-square-path}/#{$country}.svg);
    }
  }
}
```

If I wanted to create the three sizes, do I simply create three separate blocks or is there a way to create sub-elements so that the common parts don't have to be repeated.

A beginner's approach i.e. me, would be this:

```
.flag-icon-sm {
  @extend .flag-icon-background;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: (4 / 3) * 1em; // 1em for small
  line-height: 1em;
  &:before {
    content: '\00a0';
  }
  &.flag-icon-squared {
    width: 1em;
  }
}

.flag-icon-md {
  @extend .flag-icon-background;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: (4 / 3) * 2em; // 2em for medium
  line-height: 2em;
  &:before {
    content: '\00a0';
  }
  &.flag-icon-squared {
    width: 2em;
  }
}

.flag-icon-lg {
  @extend .flag-icon-background;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: (4 / 3) * 3em; // 3em for large
  line-height: 3em;
  &:before {
    content: '\00a0';
  }
  &.flag-icon-squared {
    width: 3em;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your variable sizes stay consistent throughout the flag styles, you can easily make a mixin to achieve this:

```css
@mixin flag-icon-styles($size: 1em) {
  @extend .flag-icon-background;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: (4 / 3) * $size;
  line-height: $size;
  &:before {
    content: '\00a0';
  }
  &.flag-icon-squared {
    width: $size;
  }
}

.flag-icon-sm {
  flag-icon-styles(1em);
}

.flag-icon-md {
  flag-icon-styles(2em);
}

.flag-icon-lg {
  flag-icon-styles(3em);
}
```

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/leveraging-sass-mixins-for-cleaner-code